# customize Laravel mail error on controller

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I want customize Laravel mail error page.
Now I have this page error

> (1/1) Swift_TransportException
>       Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>       535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u13sm7041792wre.52 - gsmtp
>       "

```
in AbstractSmtpTransport.php (line 383)
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u13sm7041792wre.52 - gsmtp ', array(250))
in AbstractSmtpTransport.php (line 281)
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('RSET ', array(250), array())
in EsmtpTransport.php (line 270)
```

But I want show me this error

My header

> (1/1) Swift_TransportException
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>   535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u13sm7041792wre.52 - gsmtp
>   "

My fotter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it with this

```
try {
        $email = Mail::send('sendtestmail', ['text'=>$data], function ($message) use ($data){
            $message->from('test@gmail.com', $data);
            $message->to('test@yahoo.com')->subject('test subject');
           });
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
         $params = [  'flag' => 'warning', 'flagMsg' => $ex->getMessage();
         return view("Setting::$page")->with($params);
    }
```